# How to check a checkbox if value from DB is 1 in Modal form

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to create an admin panel where the admin can edit the users rights. The rights are in from of checkboxes, which deliver 1 if the user has the right or 0 if he doesn't. All the values are passed from my overview of all users to a modal form like this:

```
  <script>
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
      var id = button.data('id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var firstname = button.data('firstname');
      var lastname = button.data('lastname');
      var email = button.data('email');
      var Admin = button.data('Admin');
      var Expert = button.data('Expert');
      var modal = $(this);
      $('#edit_form').attr('action', '{{URL::to('/')}}/AdminPanel/'+id); //No spaces!!!
      modal.find('#name_field').val(firstname);
      modal.find('#lastname_field').val(lastname);
      modal.find('#email_field').val(email);
      modal.find('#is-Admin').val(Admin);
      modal.find('#is-Expert').val(Expert);
    });
  </script>
```

On the Modal from the inputs first name, last name and email are being filled by the values passed to the modal, but somehow that is not working for my checkboxes. Which look like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-6">
    <fieldset>
      <input id='is-Admin' class="preference" name='Admin' type="checkbox" value="">
      <label for="is-Admin">Admin</label>
      <input id='is-Expert' class="preference" name='Expert' type="checkbox" value="">
      <label for="is-Expert">Expert</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 1){
      $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
  }
  this.value = (Number(this.checked));
});
</script>
```

What I basically want to achieve is that when the modal is called, if the user has the rights, then the checkbox is checked.
Thanks in advance!

Edit solution suggestion:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="Admin" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Admin?') }}</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-6">
        <label class="switch">
          <input name='Admin' type='hidden' value='0'>
          <input id='is-Admin' name='Admin' type="checkbox" value="{{ $Users['Admin'] == 'is-Admin' ? '1':'0' }}" {{ $Users['Admin'] == 'is-Admin' ? 'checked':'' }}>
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Ternary operation" like this,

```
<input id='is-Admin' class="preference" name='Admin' type="checkbox" 
value="{{ $user->role == 'is-Admin' ? '1':'0' }}" 
{{ $user->role == 'is-Admin' ? 'checked':'' }} >
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: just tried this solution, but the checkboxes are being checked even if the user doesn't have the right

Comment: Sorry I was away for some days, I will edit my question with my code @Aushraf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in jQuery I would suggest trying this:

```
if($(this).val() == 1){
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
}
```

Depending on your jQuery Version (if you got an older version, below 1.6) you may replace .prop with .attr

```
if($(this).val() == 1){
      $(this).attr("checked", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0 for false and 1 for true.

```
document.getElementById("is-Admin").checked = 0;
document.getElementById("is-Expert").checked = 1;
```

Comment: This would only allow me to hard code the values in the view, and not work with the values from the DB